# Temperature widget flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[image][image]

I have a design figma,

here is the result of my code. There are four problems here

1: Text it's not centered compared to the circle

2: I'm not sure it fits many screen sizes

3: I don't know how to create the switch below

4: I want to be able to switch between different thermometers like in the picture. How should I optimize this conversion?

[image]

This is my code:

```
                Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  children: [
                    Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      children: [
                        AppImageWidget.asset(
                          path: AppImage.bgThermometer,
                          height: widgetHeight,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 28.0.sp),
                          child: Stack(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  right: 4.0.sp,
                                  top: 12.0.sp,
                                  bottom: 2.0.sp,
                                ),
                                height: widgetHeight / 2 - 12.0.sp,
                                width: 10.0.sp,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: const Color(0xFFFF5A5A),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0.sp),
                                ),
                              ),
                              AppImageWidget.asset(
                                path: AppImage.imgThermometer,
                                height: widgetHeight / 2,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Obx(
                      () => Container(
                        width: 60.0.sp,
                        height: 60.0.sp,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 12.0.sp,
                          bottom: 12.0.sp,
                        ),
                        child: FittedBox(
                          fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                          child: Text(
                            "${controller.currentTemper} C",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: const Color(0xFFFF5A5A),
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              fontSize: 20.0.sp,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      top: 0.1 * widgetHeight,
                      left: 0.22 * widgetHeight,
                      child: Text(
                        "Feel like \n ${controller.currentTemper} C",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: const Color(0xFFFF5A5A),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          fontSize: 14.0.sp,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```